# How to use the OpenCV C++ specific sample on the Android platform?

Tags: android, opencv, surf

hi,everybody.

I need to develop a project for Object Detecting and Matching on Android platform. And i'm going to use the OpenCV.

By now , i'm having a problem.

I found the sample that is helpful but written in c++:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher

When I'm going to use JNI for this , I couldn't find some Classes of the sample in OpenCV4Android platform SDK . Such as:SurfFeatureDetector.

I use 2.4.2 version and someone say it move to nonfree but i couldn't find out nonfree in Android SDK . I doubt that the JNI include is missing some files.

So, How to use the OpenCV C++ specific sample on the Android platform?

Comment: I cant compile it. The head files of Sample is differ from OpenCV4Android. I could not find the correct head file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find nonfree in OpenCV4Android because the compiled package available to download does not include it. Your easiest solution is to use the ORB algorithm which is much more suitable for mobile because it is faster.

The sample you mention will be mostly the same but you change ORB for SURF. All the problems you will have by changing the sample from SURF to ORB you will very likely find an answer, if you search, because many people went through that process already ;)

Comment: Thank you , I would try that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/wghsite/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android), you would solve your problem.
What you need to do is to build nonfree module and use it in your project.